# c3js: Uncaught TypeError: c.forEach is not a function

Tags: c3.js

I'm trying to create a simple line-graph of points using a timeseries axis, but the chart doesn't render and my browser console shows the error:

**`c3.min.js Uncaught TypeError: c.forEach is not a function`**

Here's my javascript:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  data: {
    json: [
      {date: "2016-01-01", pageviews: 1},
      {date: "2016-01-02", pageviews: 2},
      {date: "2016-01-03", pageviews: 3},
      {date: "2016-01-04", pageviews: 4},
      {date: "2016-01-05", pageviews: 5}],
    keys: {
      x: 'date',
      value: 'pageviews'
    }
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'timeseries',
      tick: {
        format: '%Y-%m-%d'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And [here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td194yd9/) which uses the un-minified sources for D3 and C3 and gives the following browser console error: **`Uncaught TypeError: targetKeys.forEach is not a function`**

Answer (score 2):

The `data.keys.value` is expecting an array, so simply wrap `'pageviews'` in square brackets like so:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  data: {
    json: [
      {date: "2016-01-01", pageviews: 1},
      {date: "2016-01-02", pageviews: 2},
      {date: "2016-01-03", pageviews: 3},
      {date: "2016-01-04", pageviews: 4},
      {date: "2016-01-05", pageviews: 5}],
    keys: {
      x: 'date',
      value: ['pageviews']       // needs to be an array
    }
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'timeseries',
      tick: {
        format: '%Y-%m-%d'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[Working jsfiddle for completeness](https://jsfiddle.net/won51988/)